# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module xxApp due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'xxApp' is not available

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I've found following error after uglify my application controller files with `gulp`. In my previous project, I've used same `gulp` uglify code and it was working but at that time, not using `ES6` command.

i'm using that `gulp-uglifyes` plugin for uglify for ES6.

**Gulp Uglify**

```
gulp.task('appsjs', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/scripts/**/*.js')
    .pipe(gulp.dest(jsDest))
    .pipe(rename('prod.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify({ 
      mangle: false, 
      ecma: 6 
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(jsDest));
});
```

**normal app.JS file code:**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var xxApp = angular.module('xxApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize']);
    xxApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
```

**after uglify app.js**

```
!function(){"use strict";angular.module("xxApp");angular.module("xxApp").service("utilService",function()
```

Please let me know how to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: @31piy sorry forgot to replace that area, pls assume as `xxApp`.

Answer (score 0):

of course because you don't define `xxApp` in uglify

```
!function(){"use strict";angular.module("xxApp");angular.module("xxApp").service("utilService",function()
```

you directly used `angular.module('xxApp')` should be `angular.module('xxApp,[])`